# Relation between mathematical functions and trees?

Tags: data-structures, trees

I try to express datastructures in a form of mathematical functions. For example an array or a dictionary is just a function to me.

Is there a good way to model a tree in terms of functions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type

Answer (score 2):

A tree structure can be completely described by three functions:

- a function that given a node $x$ returns the number of children of that node,
- a function that given a node $x$ and index $i$ returns the $i$th child of that node, and
- a function that given a node $x$ returns an associated value $v$ stored at that node.